# Female Protagonist, Fantasy, Metal Affixed to arms

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

I am trying to find a book I read in the late 80s, possibly early 90s. 
It is a fantasy novel, although there is a bit of a post-apocalyptic feel to it. It was set in a desert. The main character is a female apprentice magic user. The magic system used involves affixing metal shapes to your body (perhaps moon or scarab shaped), which allows you to handle a higher level of magic. The metal shapes are applied with the help of a higher ranking mage. The magic users also use spell components carried in a pouch on their belt. This is less of a Harry Potter kind of magic, and more of a recipe that creates an outcome magic. At the end, the main female character needed a power boost in a hurry and tries to attach a stolen metal piece to her arm in order to become more powerful, but one of the pieces is affixed incorrectly, and it limits her ability.

Comment: Same question from [two years ago](http://whatwasthatbook.livejournal.com/3140244.html).

Comment: Well good thing we have a tried and tested [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Comment: Hmm. What was the female character's name? What magic did she do? What were the "spell components"? Who was the antagonist? Was there a love-interest? Was she on a quest? Did she have any companions? Were there any words that were unique to the novel? How was the protagonist *described*?

Comment: Snarky comments aside, this question would benefit from some additional details.  If you can remember anything, even what the cover art looked like, it could help increase your chances of finding an answer.

Comment: I honestly have looked for that long, and done multiple searches, to no avail. I want to say that this was set in the desert. The girl is an apprentice of some sort. The thin metal shapes were moons and a scarab, i think? The magic was less of a wave-your-hand and presto, but more of a recipe that leads to an outcome.

Comment: i believe that she had to steal the metal to affix to her arm, and that usually someone would help the Mage attach it, but that she needed a power boost in a hurry and botched the job.

Comment: Sorry for not noting that I had been looking for this (on the internet) for a while.

Comment: Rather than post updates here in the comments, please [edit your question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/167243/edit) to add the details.

Comment: The journal linked to in Valorum's comment is now deleted, here's an archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20170919044148/http://whatwasthatbook.livejournal.com/3140244.html